# How to install vue js in laravel 8 without jetstream and Inertia?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a project with Laravel 8 version and I want to work with vue js components without installing jetstream and inertia. Is it needed to install Jetstream with inertai in order to work with vue js in laravel 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you need to install laravel/ui package by running `composer require laravel/ui:^2.4` as Said in [laravel doc version 7](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#introduction)

After that, you should run `php artisan ui vue` for adding vue scaffolding to the project.

Comment: You don't need to install Laravel UI for Vue.

Comment: @Rwd I felt that the question is looking for a predefined scaffolding for vue development and larave/ui provides that scaffolding. However, it is clear that vue doesn't need laravel/ui, it is a javascript framework and can be installed individually.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any additional Laravel components to use Vue. You only need npm or yarn to install packages and create a composer.json file. Follow the instructions at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ (for Vue2) or https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html for (Vue3) for installation.

For Laravel/Vue, Vue will be used as a front-end, which will use ajax/Axios to use GET/POST requests to Laravel for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

after create laravel project,you need to install laravel/ui and don't specify the version

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

then run `php artisan ui vue --auth` for Generate login / registration
scaffolding...

`php artisan ui vue` without login/registration